# NSCompoundPredicate factory method confusion

Tags: xcode, swift, nspredicate, xcode7-beta4

I have some code in a project that I recently updated to Swift 2.0:

```
return NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: fieldPreds)
```

This originally read

```
return NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates(fieldPreds)
```

But the compiler told me this was no longer a class method, I should use the init method.  Fine.  But, when I git-push this project over to my other system, running the same beta of Xcode and the same version of OS X, it won't compile, I get an error:

> Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSCompoundPredicate' that accepts an argument list of type '(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [NSPredicate])'

One system seems to be aware of the new prototype but one isn't..., all the target and build settings appear to be identical, they're part of the commit so I don't see where the problem could be.

Comment: Include your init statement.

Comment: Ruh?  Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: "But the compiler told me ... I should use the init method" - what was that `init` statement?

Comment: I originally had the class method, the one that goes `Class.orPred`; I switched it to an init method, the one that goes `Class(orPred...)`  The compiler on one machine wants me to use the first line, the compiler on the other machine wants me to do it the other way.

Comment: It is a shot in the dark, but did you try cleaning temporary build files on the second machine?

Comment: Sorry I think this was me, I'm using the same SDK on both Xcode's but a different beta build